# Cannot post radio value in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

view:

```
<?php 

$attr_form = array('class' => 'form-horizontal');

echo form_open('login/create', $attr_form); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php echo form_radio('gender', 'M'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('gender', 'F'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <?php 
        $data_submit = array('class'=> 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'submit', 'value'=> 'Create Account');
        echo form_submit($data_submit);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

controllers:

```
function create ()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->signup();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('parents_model');
        if($query = $this->parents_model->create_member())
        {
            $data['main_content'] = 'successful';
            $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
        }

        else
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
    }
}
```

model:

```
function create_member ()
{
    $new_parents = array(
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender')
        );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('parents', $new_parents);
    return $insert;
}
```

I just simplified the other form inputs. 
Can anyone figure out whats wrong with my code? It cannot go to successful page.
Or do I use wrong form_radio code ?

I have tried many times! Please help me....

Comment: Your **model** should **NOT** have direct input from **POST** as your models should only have CLEAN and valid data sent to them. Don't use post/get inside your model.

Comment: Can you share result of `var_dump($_POST);` in `create_member` model ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
$this->input->post->('gender')
```

should be:

```
$this->input->post('gender')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$gender = $this->input->post('gender')['M'] ? 'M':'F';
$new_parents = array('gender' => $gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

After I restarted my localhost, everything works again.
Cause I have created a column in the table without restarting!